# Field_image width in views

Tags: views, 8, media

I need to build a view with image  width and height available in the node  devel tab (see image). In the view field list, I can't find those.

How can I have these values in my view?

note: Having this data already, I prefer not to install more modules as exif or similar.

[image]

Comment: How would you like to use the image width and height? Through views field or node template file?

Comment: I need width value as sortable view table field.